# Mysql retrieve only specific values from n:n relation

Tags: mysql

Say we have following Mysql tables:

**user:**

```
userID | user_name
```

**classification:**

```
classificationID | classification_name | classification_ponder
```

**user_classification:**

```
userId(PK) | classificationId(PK)
```

This is n:n relationship between user and classifiaction.

I am interested how to query for *every user, ALL classifications with biggest ponder in one column, separated with `,`*?

E.g. let say we have user1 with ID=1 and following classifications:

```
 classificationId | classification_name | classification_ponder
---------------------------------------------------------------
        1                 class1                     5 
        2                 class2                     5 
        3                 class3                     4
        4                 class4                     2
```

user_classification table is(user have all classifications):

```
 userId | ClassificationId
---------------------------
    1            1
    1            2
    1            3
    1            4
```

What I want to get is:

```
userId | user_name | class1, class2
```

So only classification names with biggest ponder (in this case `class1` and `class2`) displayed in one column, separated with ",".

I succeed to get all classifications for user with following mysql query:

```
select 
  user.user_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Classification.classification_name) as Classification 
from user 
left join user_classification 
  on (user_classification.userId=user.userID) 
left join Classification 
  on (Classification.classificationID=user_classification.classificationId) 
GROUP BY user.userID</b>
```

**What i want is do display only classifications with biggest ponder.**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    u.user_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.classification_name) as Classification
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        user_classification.userId as uid,
        MAX(classification.classification_ponder as max_ponder
    FROM user_classification
    INNER JOIN classification ON user_classification.classificationId = classification.classificationID
    GROUP BY user_classification.userId
) as user_max ON u.userID = user_max.uid
LEFT JOIN user_classification uc ON u.userID = uc.userId
LEFT JOIN classification c ON uc.classificationId = c.classificationID AND user_max.max_ponder = c.classification_ponder
GROUP BY u.userID
```

Something like this should do the trick (can have some syntax errors)